# Login to desktop failure

Tags: system, graphic-drivers, settings

Tried to install the nVidia driver, but it always reverts to the default driver.

The way I log in to do this is to enter recovery mode and run fsck and then resume. During these steps it complains about files having future times of less than a day, and then installs a 1.4mb file with the word "yelp" in the name and then it boots straight to the desktop without any login.

I installed elementary oS to boot straight to the desktop with no login. Now, every reboot brings me to a login screen.

What gets the computer to boot correctly is to enter recovery mode, run `fsck`, and then resume.

`fsck` reports "Last mount time and write time is in the future (by less than a day, probably due to the hardware clock being incorrectly set)

Then it reports it is fixed - both the mount and write - and then it boots as it should.

The bios battery is relatively new, and seems to hold it's info. When I entered the CMOS - one time only - it was using a weird character for the dates year. But it hasn't done that again. Is this a bad battery, corrupt BIOS or something else?

Comment: Thought I should be more accurate in the dialog. I installed elementary os to boot straight to the desktop with no login. Now, every reboot brings me to a login screen. (with an added guest account - since removed) What gets the computer to boot correctly is the enter recovery mode, run fsck, and then resume. (I found running dpkg was unnecessary).

Comment: fsck reports "Last mount time and write time is in the future (by less than a day, probably due to the hardware clock being incorrectly set) FIXED is reported for both mount and write - and then it boots as it should. The bios battery is relatively new, and seems to hold it's info. When I entered the cmos - one time only - it was using a weird character for the dates year. But it hasn't done that again. Is this a bad battery, corrupt bios or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on this computer. (Asus A7M266-D, 2800+x2 - It seems to like Lubuntu 15.10 though) It was too old for Elementary OS - I fear. I replaced the bios battery, and other hardware changes, but could never get rid of this "future" error. I am now using Elementary OS on a different computer i built - 64bit based - and it runs great. I think the take away from this is that the dually AMD based boards from 10-15 years ago (AMD chipset) may be problematic. I have a Tyan Tiger MP I may test this on in the future.